# Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert generic method overloads behavior

Tags: c#

In the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` namespace, there is the handy static class `Assert` to handle the assertions going on in your tests.

Something that has got me bugged is that most methods are extremely overloaded, and on top of that, they have a generic version. One specific example is `Assert.AreEqual` which has 18 overloads, among them:

```
Assert.AreEqual<T>(T t1, T t2)
```

What is the use of this generic method? Originally, I thought this was a way to directly call the `IEquatable<T> Equals(T t)` method, but that is not the case; it will always call the non-generic version `object.Equals(object other)`. I found out the hard way after coding quite a few unit tests expecting that behavior (instead of examining the `Assert` class definition beforehand like I should have).

In order to call the generic version of `Equals`, the generic method would had to be defined as:

```
Assert.AreEqual<T>(T t1, T t2) where T: IEquatable<T>
```

Is there a good reason why it wasn't done this way?

Yes, you loose the generic method for all those types that don't implement `IEquatable<T>`, but it's not a great loss anyway as equality would be checked through `object.Equals(object other)`, so `Assert.AreEqual(object o1, object o2)` is already good enough.

Does the current generic method offer advantages I'm not considering, or is it just the case that no one stopped to think about it as it's not that much of a deal? The only advantage I see is argument type safety, but that seems kind of poor.

**Edit**: fixed an error where I kept referring to `IComparable` when I meant `IEquatable`.

Comment: You can't constrain it, as any T without its own overload would naturally resolve to that method as a part of overload resolution and only then have the compiler complain about the unfulfilled constraint for any T that does not implement the interface. As for your incorrect assumption, did you check the method's documentation before building your test strategy around it?

Comment: AnthonyPegram: if you constraint it you can't pass in any T that doesn't implement the interface so how exactly would overload resolution fail in runtime?

Comment: It would fail at compile time, but overload resolution would have already decided on the T overload and *then* check the constraint (and fail). Constraints are not part of the signature. If you search that phrase, you'll find plenty of resources (here and elsewhere, notably Eric Lippert's blog) that will give you more detail on that.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I don't follow you. There is no ambiguity here. If you explicitly call the generic method and pass in a T that does not meet the constraint, method overload has nothing to do with the issue at all. You get a compile time error saying type Foo does not implement IEquatable<Foo>. Another issue is if you let type inference decide if the generic method is the better fit, but that isn't what I'm asking.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Ok I think I see what you mean. The issue is that if I don't explicitly call the generic method, overload resolution will still choose the generic version and fail at compile time. In order to call the (object, object) overload I would have to explicitly cast at least one argument to object. Is that it? Ok, that seems a pretty good reason ;)

Comment: *Any* T would *automatically* resolve to that method! That's the issue! Say you have `class Bar { }`. It would resolve to that method. `Assert.AreEqual(new Bar(), new Bar())` would fail to compile, with that constraint in place. You would have to make the call as `Assert.AreEqual((object)new Bar(), new Bar())` to have it pick the non-T overload using `object`. Would that be ideal? Would you design a unit testing method with that unfriendly limitation?

Comment: I have moved the basic points of this conversation into an answer, now that I am free from the shackles of my workday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method having that constraint would be non-ideal because of the oft-faced problem of [constraints not being part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

The issue would be that for any T that is not covered by its own specific overload, the compiler would choose the generic `AreEqual<T>` method as the best fit during overload resolution, as it would indeed by an exact match. In a different step of the process, the compiler would evaluate that T passes the constraint. For any T that does not implement `IEquatable<T>`, this check would fail and the code would not compile.

Consider this simplified example of the unit testing library code and a class that might exist in your library:

```
public static class Assert
{
    public static void AreEqual(object expected, object actual) { }
    public static void AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual) where T : IEquatable<T> { }
}

class Bar { }
```

Class Bar does not implement the interface in the constraint. If we were then to add the following code to a unit test

```
Assert.AreEqual(new Bar(), new Bar());
```

The code would fail to compile because of the unsatisfied constraint on the method that is the best candidate. (`Bar` substitutes for T, which makes it a better candidate than `object`.)

> > The type 'Bar' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Assert.AreEqual<T>(T, T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Bar' to 'System.IEquatable<Bar>'.

In order to satisfy the compiler and allow our unit test code to compile and run, we would have to cast at least one input to the method to `object` so that the non-generic overload can be chosen, and this would be true for *any* given T that might exist in your own code or code you consume that you wish to use in your test cases that does not implement the interface.

```
Assert.AreEqual((object)new Bar(), new Bar());
```

So the question must be asked -- would that be ideal? If you were writing a unit testing library, would you create such a method with such an unfriendly limitation? I suspect you would not, and the implementers of the Microsoft unit testing library (whether it was for this reason or not) did not either.

Comment: +1 Thanks for making me understand what is going on. Makes me wonder though why type constraints are not part of the overload resolution... Also makes me wonder why the compiler throws an error instead of issuing a warning and falling back to the `AreEqual(object expected ...` one.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the generic overload force you to compare two objects of same type. In case you change type of expecting or actual value, the compilation error will appear. Here is [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/12/11/why-use-areequal-t.aspx) describing it quite well.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mention in the question...the only advantage is argument type safety but so find this reason rather poor in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

You can decompile the method and see that all it really does is add a type check (via ILSpy), which isn't even done correctly in my opinion (it checks types after equality):

```
public static void AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
    message = Assert.CreateCompleteMessage(message, parameters);
    if (!object.Equals(expected, actual))
    {
        string message2;
        if (actual != null && expected != null && !actual.GetType().Equals(expected.GetType()))
        {
            message2 = FrameworkMessages.AreEqualDifferentTypesFailMsg((message == null) ? string.Empty : Assert.ReplaceNulls(message), Assert.ReplaceNulls(expected), expected.GetType().FullName, Assert.ReplaceNulls(actual), actual.GetType().FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            message2 = FrameworkMessages.AreEqualFailMsg((message == null) ? string.Empty : Assert.ReplaceNulls(message), Assert.ReplaceNulls(expected), Assert.ReplaceNulls(actual));
        }
        Assert.HandleFailure("Assert.AreEqual", message2);
    }
}
```

Theoretically, it could use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to use the generic Equals, if available, but which would fallback to non-generic Equals otherwise. This would then not require a constraint to `IEquatable<T>`. Having a different behavior for the generic and non-generic Equals methods are a code smell, IMO.

Honestly, the generic overload is not tremendously useful unless you type out the generic parameter. I cannot count how many times I've mistyped a property or compared two properties that are different types and it picked the `AreEqual(object,object)` overload. Thus giving me a failure much later at run time rather than compile time.